# What feature is causing these code hints to appear in VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ide

This "feature" seems to have randomly appeared in my Visual Studio 2010 functionality. I have a year-old build of [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/), and [VSCommands](http://vscommands.com/) Lite installed, but haven't changed any of my editor settings recently. I installed the [Achievements](http://channel9.msdn.com/achievements/visualstudio) add-in recently, but that seems unlikely to have enabled this feature. Where did this come from? I'd like to show coworkers how to enable it, but can't figure out where, how, or why this magical new feature now appears in my editor.

The feature shows faint grey statements that echo the opening brace of a statement that's no longer visible beyond the scrollable window off of the screen. For example:

[image: What is this feature?]

Comment: I don't have ReSharper and so I haven't seen those code hints.  Can you show your Tools -> Options to see if there's anything in there for ReSharper?

Comment: I don't think it is ReSharper.  It has a similar functionality, but it doesn't look like that.  I've never used VSCommands Lite, but I would guess that is doing it.  Start uninstalling Add-Ins and wait for it to disappear.

Comment: I don't think it's ReSharper, which I've had installed and haven't updated or changed the settings for it anytime recently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out the new functionality *is* part of VSCommands Lite, which auto-updated itself recently (the latest version was released a few weeks ago). The update added and enabled this new ["Code block tagger"](http://vscommands.com/releasenotes/3.8.0.0) feature.

[image: This is it.]

Comment: It contains a bug? "*if ( WindowState == WindowState.Open)*" isn't gray

Comment: When you hover over one of these, it fades to full black, and you can click it to move the cursor to that point. The screenshot doesn't seem to include the cursor, but that's most likely where it was pointing when it was taken. Pretty sweet feature.

Comment: Cool! I even think that's a great feature!